# SAPUI5 Smart Filter Bar: Is it possible to add custom buttons in a Freestyle app?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm using the RAP framework with a Fiori Freestyle app (In SAP Business Application Studio), showing a smart table with a Smart Filter Bar.

I already have a Date Range filter, which I'm pre-populating with a range of 4 weeks from today.

My question is, how do I customise the Smart Filter bar to include, for example, a 'Previous 4 weeks' and a 'Next 4 weeks' button?

I checkout out some SAP documentation and found this can be done in Fiori Elements...

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/3a515829ffd74239878ebc0d453d001d.html

But can it be done with a Freestyle app? And if so, how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart Filter Bar allows you to define custom fields on top of the ones which you get from your entity model/annotations. You could check [this sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smartfilterbar.SmartFilterBar/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfilterbar.CustomField) which adds an extra MultiComboBox via controlConfiguration.

Following this, you could add a [sap.m.DynamicDateRange](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.m.DynamicDateRange) control (see samples) to the filter bar which gives you relative date filtering.